# Seeing actual maven invocations

Tags: java, maven-2

Is there a way to get Maven to include in its logs the actual commands that were invoked to perform a particular operation? I'm having a problem where a javac invocation is failing and I'd like to see what maven was actually trying to do.

Comment: The assumption here is you've already tried -e command line option to show errors.

Comment: The -X option, by the way, produces voluminous information but does not actually include the invocation (sigh)

Comment: Yes, that's a good assumption.... the -e option shows a stacktrace when mvn fails but it doesn't help to show what went wrong when it invokes a program with wrong arguments. I get the error below (on my Mac only, everything works fine on Windows and Linux) 

and to figure out what's wrong, it would be kind of useful to know what mvn actually tried to execute!

[INFO] Compilation failure
Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
javac: -bootclasspath requires an argument
Usage: javac <options> <source files>

Comment: I solved the particular problem by adding a profile to my maven settings.xml file to indicate that java 1.6 needs to be used. However, it would still be very helpful to be able to see the actual command invocations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-X is the closest you will get. It's up to the plugin (compiler in this case) to log useful information. Maven will always log the values passed to the plugin, but here compiler calls off to JavaC and apparently it's not logging what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it *can* log what you want.  I think it calls the compiler directly, inside the same JVM.  So there is no command line to show.

Comment: That can't be the case, given the error message that I got, which was clearly an incorrect call to javac.